# RSpec: Create mock / stub a hierarchical object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

How can I create a mock / stub for the following object using RSpec:

```
User.current.instance.custom_field
```

returning a specific such as `"foo"` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rspec` provides an option to stub chain methods

```
User.stub_chain(:current, :instance, :custom_field).and_return("foo")
```

Have a look at the documentation for chain stub [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-3/docs/method-stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods)